# GRAV cms how to use image from theme folder in page theme

Tags: twig, grav

I would like to use image, that user can upload to the theme folder and show it on any page. I would like to use media functions like: **negate, lightbox, cropZoom** on this image.
I do know how to display images as it is, by using this code:

```
<img src="{{ url("theme://images/pages/" ~ category.image) }}" alt="{{ category.category_name|e }}" />
```

But I can not use any of above functions.
More over I was trying to use a markdown but even if I did set config and put markdown=“1” in my template I wasn't able to use markdow – it was showing like literal without compilation, even when I was using code from:
https://learn.getgrav.org/cookbook/general-recipes#wrapping-markdown-into-html

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is impossible becouse according to GRAV documentation: https://learn.getgrav.org/content/image-linking

> If you decide to use a centralized image directory, be advised that this directory should exist within the /pages folder as this folder is intended for front-facing content.

I should read it ealier.